# open PDF link within application in Android

Tags: android, pdf

I am having a problem in opening a **URL** that has a **PDF document** within my android application. The **pdf** should be opened within the application, it should not open in **external browser**. There is also another condition and that is I should not save or store the pdf anywhere(sdcard or phone memory). Please let me know how to proceed with this. For example, you can take this [link](http://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/W_0300_CodingforLife-BatteryLifeThatIs.pdf) to try out. I have no idea about how to proceed to make it work. Please help me out. Thank you all.

Comment: Do you use android webview for this?

Comment: android webview I used but its giving download option at the bottom of the page. The requirement is it should not be there.